# Trying to make navbar active - I include my single nav_bar.jsp file to all my files

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, navbar

So I have one file which has my nav bar: nav_bar.jsp. In this file, I have this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- navbar links -->
                <li class="active"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myinfo/">My Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/reimbursements/">Reimbursements</a></li>
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/employees/">Employees</a></li>
            </ul>
```

(My url has a regex which is checking for the path)

Anyway, all my files include this file with the following:

```
<%@ include file="nav_bar.jsp" %>  <%-- Bringing in nav bar  --%>
```

The navbar shows perfectly fine. However, I'm trying to change the class "active" depending on the tab that is open. I was trying to do it with JS, but it still doesn't work. I tried this

default.js

```
$('.navbar-nav li').click( function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Note: I'm getting my JS in the nav_bar.jsp and also every other page with this as the last tag in the head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/JS/default.js"></script>
```

I read somewhere that I had to add JS in the bottom of the body tag? I wasn't sure if that was true. I tried it but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are navigating into a new page when you are clicking on a new tab so changing anything in javascript wouldn't do a thing as a new page will be loaded and the DOM will be refreshed.

One way to set the active class is based on the request url. You could do that either via HTML tags or JavaScript. For HTML tags do something like the below: (You will have to do it for every tab (adjust the condition as you need for each link))

```
<li class="${pageContext.request.requestURI.endsWith('/index/') ? 'active' : ''}">
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index/">Home</a>
</li>
```

Note: I just assumed the condition for your first link. You may want to adjust that to cover broader requests etc